# Resizing Background Images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML. Can anyone please tell me how can I resize the background image in CSS?

Comment: Have a look at [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: What I am trying to do is that I used the bootstrap grid to do 3 paragraphs of text.  I want each paragraph to have a background image and I want to set the size of the image but it is not working :/

Comment: Can you post some code to at least show an attempt to solve the problem? SO isn't a code writing service - you have to show some code that we can help you with when it errors out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS background-size property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

I hope that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Keywords syntax

background-size: cover;
background-size: contain;

One-value syntax
the width of the image (height set to 'auto')

background-size: 50%;
background-size: 3em;
background-size: 12px;
background-size: auto;

Two-value syntax
first value: width of the image, second value: height

background-size: 50% auto;
background-size: 3em 25%;
background-size: auto 6px;
background-size: auto auto;

Multiple backgrounds values by background-image
Do not confuse this with background-size: auto auto
background-size: auto, auto;
background-size: 50%, 25%, 25%;
background-size: 6px, auto, contain;

background-size: inherit;

more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

img{ width:100%;}

Add this into your css and use !important if necessary. this will work.